# Render grid items in one row - ReactJS and Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-grid, react-flexbox-grid

I want to create a material ui carousel that has 3 items visible in the same row. When shrinking the browser's width I want the items to be still in one row and just hide the ones who don't fit.

This is when full screen:

[image]

This is what i want to have:

[image]

But this is what i get instead:

[image]

Do you have any ideas about what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```js
  <Paper variant="outlined" className={classes.paper}>
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={2}
      className={classes.grid}
      alignItems="center"
      justify="center"
    >
      ...
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" className={classes.box}>
        <Grid item xs="auto" className={classes.arrow}>
          ...Left Arrow...
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={2}
            className={classes.grid}
            alignItems="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <Grid item xs="auto">
              <UserCard content={users[index]} />
            </Grid>
            <Hidden xsDown>
              <Grid item xs="auto">
                <UserCard content={users[index + 1]} />
              </Grid>
            </Hidden>
            <Hidden smDown>
              <Grid item xs="auto">
                <UserCard content={users[index + 2]} />
              </Grid>
            </Hidden>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs="auto" className={classes.arrow}>
          ...Right Arrow...
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </Grid>
  </Paper>
```

Styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "auto",
  },
  grid: {
    width: "auto",
  },
  arrow: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  box: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));
```

Comment: There should be something else affecting the styles because it works in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-material-ui-forked-m0z6m?file=/src/Foo.tsx

Comment: @Zabzuki what is the screen resolution that you are using?

Comment: @ShivamJha it's 1920x1080

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your `Grid container` add `wrap='nowrap'` prop. Which overwrite the default `wrap='wrap'`.

```
<Grid
    container
    wrap='nowrap'
    // Your other props
>
```

**Explanation**
By default, if items doesn't fit in the container, they simply wrap and move to the next row.

With `wrap='nowrap'` prop, Grid items stay on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useMediaQuery provided by Material UI to check if you need to render the last component

https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/